# C++11 Strongly-typed enums in Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, c++11, enums, gnu

I have the error:

> Expected ';' after top level declarator

Xcode suggest to add ; after AABBCC.

When I compile

```
enum class AABBCC
{
    AA, BB, CC
};
```

This is in an .h file.
Type = C++ Header

Configuration:

> Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C = Default compiler (Apple LLVM 5.1) C++
>
> Language Dialect = GNU++11[-std=gnu++11]

Comment: It's probably something before/above the `enum` declaration that's causing the problem. Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: ^ as godel9 suggested, can you post the surroundings of your header file?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that this header file is included in a C source file ?

Comment: Yup, that would do it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this header file is included in a C source file.